# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with custom authentication filter - dependency issue

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I have spring security configuration with SPNEGO which is working "with a hack". It looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpnegoConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                ...
                .addFilterBefore(
                        spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean()),
                        BasicAuthenticationFilter.class); // 1
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired // 3
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth
                .authenticationProvider(kerberosAuthenticationProvider())
                .authenticationProvider(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider());
    }


    @Bean
    public SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) { // 2
        SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter =
                new SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return filter;
    }
    ...
}
```

What is happening:

- I need to add spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter (1)
- This filter has dependency on authenticationManager (2)
- I need to add authentication providers (3)

Point being in this class which is `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` I'm overriding 2 methods:

1. `configure(HttpSecurity http)` - this has dependency on the already built `AuthenticationManager` through custom filter
2. `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` - this clearly relates on `AuthenticationManager` no being built yet - we're building it

If I don't have the `@Autowired` on method (3) the `AuthenticationManager` is built too early and my adding of `AuthenticationProvider`s has no effect. The authentication fails with exception there is no suitable `AuthenticationProvider`.

With the `@Autowired` in place it works but if feels wrong. I'm not even sure why it starts working then.

Please advice on the right approach.

**Edit:** It actually works without the @Autowired. But the point is in the accepted answer. If you ever depend on `AuthenticationManager` in `@Configuration` make sure it's either exposed or referenced via the `authenticationManagerBean()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong `AuthenticationManager`.

If you want to use the `AuthenticationManager` from `SpnegoConfig` with dependency injection, you have to expose it, see [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#authenticationManagerBean--):

> Override this method to expose the AuthenticationManager from configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) to be exposed as a Bean. For example:
>
> ```
> @Bean(name name="myAuthenticationManager")
> @Override
> public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
>    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
> }
> ```

If you want to configure global `AuthenticationManager`, you have to autowire the `AuthenticationMangerBuilder`, see [Spring Security 3.2.0.RC2 Released](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/spring-security-3-2-0-rc2-released#objectpostprocessor-quiesent-postprocessor-removed)

> For example, if you want to configure global authentication (i.e. you only have a single AuthenticationManager) you should autowire the AuthenticationMangerBuilder:
>
> ```
> @Autowired
> public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
>    // ... configure it ...
> }
> ```